# Save to SharePoint from Office custom dialog box

Tags: office-365

I would like to hide options from my users because they are getting confused with all the options, so for example they dont need to see:

- Site Assets
- Site Library

Is there any way to hide certain items or even create your own custom view?

[image]

Comment: when the site assets style library page loads, you can  fire a jQuery,JavaScript and SPServices function to hide/show.This function can be written in a content editor web part. Also you can go ahead with the  jsom/ecma script approach.

Comment: @SaMolPP. It's a layout page and you won't be able to add a CEWP in such a simple manner.

Comment: Related to the above we need to do the same only we would like to remove the code in TYPE from the view users get but here's the thing, we are using SharePoint Online. Do I need to use the SharePoint Designer or is this a setting under site settings perhaps?[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuxjA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuxjA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your site in SharePoint Designer:

1. Click on List and Libraries on LHS
2. Right Click on the list you want to hide and click on List Settings
3. When you are on List Settings tab, there is a check box to "Hide From Browser". Check it and save.

Now your list would be hidden from business.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't want to hide them in the browser only when save from an office application

Comment: Site Assets and Site Library is generally used by admin only. Why not just make a shortcut of them on the site and hide it completely. Hiding doesnt mean you'll restrict access to it.

Comment: Thanks I have it working great now, quick question, How do I change the blue logo in the top left of the window to a custom logo?

Comment: navigate to yoursiteurl/_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx there you can change the logo.

Comment: When I navigate to mysiteurl/_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx in the browser it takes me to the page to change the logo for the SharePoint site which I have already changed to the custom logo, I want to change the logo in the screenshot above

Comment: it is actually part of site logo..You sure its being reflected on site all contents page?

Comment: Yeah the logo was changed about a month ago and is visible across all content